# How can i get a minimal latency in audio recording and playing at the same time without using Oboe Library?

Tags: android, audiotrack, audiorecord, low-latency

I´m recording and playing audio using audioRecord and audioTrack, is working fine but with delay. After some research I only found things about Oboe Library (OpenSl and Aaudio). I want to resuce the latency the best as can be reduce using audioRecord and audioTrack but I don't know if it is possible.
This is part of my code:

```
protected void recordAndPlay() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

    final int bufferSizeIn = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(freq,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    final int bufferSizeOut = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(freq,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION/*MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC*/, freq,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSizeIn);

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, freq,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSizeOut,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    buffer = new short[bufferSizeIn];//buffer de amostras
    audioRecord.startRecording(); //começa a captar a voz
    Log.i("", "Audio Recording started");
    audioTrack.play(); //começa a transmitir a voz
    Log.i("", "Audio Playing started");
    Rthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSizeIn);
                    audioTrack.write(buffer,0,bufferSizeIn);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Read write failed");
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Rthread.start();
}
```

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/audio-latency